# How do you remove a station from a line?

Tags: mini-metro

I'm able to add more stations and modify their lines, but can't change the line to include fewer or different stations.

Can you remove a line's junction? How do you remove a station from a line?

Edit: I play on the cellphone version of the game. Don't know if it changes something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know on the PC version of the game that you click and drag on the line until it is over the station you want to remove. Have you tried that?

Comment: Note: If you play on Extreme Mode, you can't change lines. So you can't remove stations from lines either.